# Размытие шрифта при установки значения bold

Tags: html, css

Слева требуемы результат, справа как получается у меня:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня шрифт получается как будто размытый. В чем может быть причина?
Мои настройки:

```
color: rgb(75, 79, 88);
display: block;
font-family: "PT Sans Narrow", san-serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-stretch: 100%;
font-style: normal;
font-variant-caps: normal;
font-variant-east-asian: normal;
font-variant-ligatures: normal;
font-variant-numeric: normal;
font-weight: 700;
height: 16px;
line-height: 16.8px;
width: 590px;
```

Настройки требуемого результата:

```
color: rgb(75, 79, 88);
display: block;
font-family: "PT Sans Narrow", sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-stretch: 100%;
font-style: normal;
font-variant-caps: normal;
font-variant-east-asian: normal;
font-variant-ligatures: normal;
font-variant-numeric: normal;
font-weight: 700;
height: 16px;
line-height: 16.8px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
max-height: 999999px;
width: 949px;
-webkit-box-direction: normal
```

Настройки брал из chrome elements->computed. Использую только браузер Chrome

Comment: `line-height:16.8px` попробуйте сделать не дробное значение

Answer (score 0):

Мутное гэ получается скорее всего из-за сглаживания шрифтов браузером или операционкой.
Проблема в том, что то, что дизайнер нарисовал в фотошопе, не всегда в принципе реализуемо иначе как вставкой графики.

Поиграйте со свойством `-webkit-font-smoothing`.

Comment: это не рисованное в фотошопе, первая надпись на сайте с которого копирую, а вторая как у меня получается